# Validation of checkbox mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, checkbox, data-annotations

I realise this question has been asked before but I am still struggling with validating this checkbox using data annotations. What am I missing. As it is right now the checkbox is not validated

view model

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return value != null && value is bool && (bool)value;
        }

    }
    [Display(Name = "I accept the terms and conditions")]
    [Required]
    [MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please accept terms and conditions")]
    public bool TermsConditions { get; set; }
```

Razor and html

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TermsConditions)
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TermsConditions, new { id = "chkTermsAndConditions" })
        Yes

  </div>
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TermsConditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine but is only server side validation. In your Action method, do this:

```
public ActionResult Terms(Terms terms)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //If checkbox isn't ticked, your code will end up in here
    }
}
```